# Adding an item to array in React fails when using sockets

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sockets, spread

I've an array in React (using hooks), and I'm using socket.io to get notified on new items.

I've defined the Socket listener on the initializing useEffect, I'm getting notified when new objects should be added, but on this listener handler -

- The current array is always empty
- When I add the new object to the beginning of the array (using the spread operator) - the array will hold only the new object.

Any idea why?

```
function RecommendationsFeed() {
    const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState<Recommendation[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(SOCKET_URL);

        socket.on('recommendation', (newRecommendation: Recommendation) => {
              newRecommendation.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
                const mergedRecommendationsList = [newRecommendation, ...recommendations];
                setRecommendations(mergedRecommendationsList);
        });
    }, []);

    return ( 
        <div>
            { recommendations.map( currRec => <RecommendationFeedItem rec={currRec} key={currRec.id}/> ) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've also tried to add the recommendations state to the parameter list of the useEffect, but then it caused the listener to get processed multiple times.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
    }, [recommendations]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Referring to the existing recommendations array in the set did the trick - by changing the update to:

```
setRecommendations((recommendations) => [newRecommendation, ...recommendations]);
```